# Show that $g$ is continuous using the fact that $f$ is unformily continuous

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Working through Advanced Calculus of Several Variables by Edwards. The section is entitled Step Functions and Riemann Sums.

Here is the question:

Let $A$ and $B$ be contented sets, and $f: A \times B \rightarrow R$ be a uniformly continuous function.

If $g: A \rightarrow R$ is defined by $g(x) = \int_Bf(x,y)dy$ for all $x \in A$ prove that $g$ is uniformly continuous.

He also gives a hint, which is the root of my question:

Write $g(x) - g(a) = \int_B [f(x,y) - f(a,y)]dy$ and apply the uniform continuity of $f$

I have no idea what the book means by applying the uniform continuity of $f$, I thought it was just a property...

Any type of help is apperciated as always,

Thank you guys for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition of what it means for $f$ to be uniformly continuous, for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there is a $\delta > 0$ so that $|f(\mathbf{x}) - f(\mathbf{y})| < \varepsilon$ for every $\mathbf{x} = (x_1,y_1),\mathbf{y} = (x_2,y_2) \in A\times B$ with $\|\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{y}\| < \delta$.

So let $\varepsilon > 0$. To show that $g$ is uniformly continuous, we must find a $\delta > 0$ so that $|g(x)-g(y)| < \varepsilon$ for all $x,y \in A$ with $|x-y| < \delta$.

Let us first apply the uniform continuity of $f$. Again, since $f$ is uniformly continuous, there is a $\delta > 0$ so that $|f(\mathbf{x}) - f(\mathbf{y})| < \varepsilon/(2|B|)$ for every $\mathbf{x} = (x_1,y_1),\mathbf{y} = (x_2,y_2) \in A\times B$ with $\|\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{y}\| < \delta$. Here $|B|$ is the volume of $B$ and it's okay to assume it is positive for otherwise $g$ is automatically uniformly continuous because it'd be the constant zero function. Now, for every $x,a \in A$ with $|x-a| < \delta$, note that $\|(x,y) - (a,y)\| = |x - a| <\delta$ for every $y \in B$, so we can apply the uniform continuity of $f$. Thus, for every $x,a \in A$ with $|x-a| < \delta$, we have
$$
|g(x) - g(a)| = \left|\int_B f(x,y) - f(a,y) dx \right| \leq \int_B |f(x,y) - f(a,y)| dy \leq \int_B \frac{\varepsilon}{2|B|} dx = \frac{\varepsilon}{2} < \varepsilon
$$
proving the uniform continuity of $g$.

Comment: I see... so thats what that meant... Thanks! That makes a lot of sense.

Comment: No problem! Glad it helped.